# Is SODDI still working with Data Dump?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, data-dump

I'm following this guide: [How to Query the StackExchange Databases](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/how-to-query-the-stackexchange-databases/), but when trying to connect with SQL Server 2014 it doesn't let me connect to the db.

Does SODDI work for the data of January 2015?

Is there any other way to get the schema of Stack Overflow with or without the data?

Comment: If you are only looking for the schema you can check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) for the schema or my [answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250396/database-diagram-of-stack-exchange-model/250439#250439) for a graphical representation. I'm not sure if support question with regard to [soddi](https://github.com/peschkaj/soddi) aren't better raised at the github project.

Comment: You can leave a comment on the blog post and use the blog's [contact page](http://www.brentozar.com/contact/) - anyhow since Brent works for SE as well, this might fit here as well and he might answer this.

Comment: @rene Really Thanks, other question that i have is, how does SE manage all the sites?, i mean each community has it's own database, but, is there a mother db? where the account is related? because the table Users has a FK "AccountId" so, are we able to see that db?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I post a comment there, thanks

Comment: Cheers, keep us updated here. :)

Comment: @Nonexistent yes, there is a mother db but that one is NOT pushed to SEDE. [SEDE has one extra database `Data.StackExchange`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/303790) that holds the accounts for SEDE (they are separated from SE accounts), the sites and the queries created by users. Us mortals don't have access to that. AccountId is a stable key across databases. I used that fact in [this answer of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247660/158100)

Comment: @rene So that we don't have access to "Data.StackExchange" ?, what you mean by stable key? it is managed on the app side?

Comment: The accountid is the unique id for any user across all sites. So on each site you have a unique userid but that can and will change per site. The accountid is the key that should be used if you want to link the same user across sites. That is why I say that accountid is stable opposed to userid which will change per site while it is the same user. But there is no table for us available that holds extra data belonging to an accountid